# java unique permutations of elements in a list

Tags: java, arraylist

The following snippet of code is found very often through my project, I feel like there must exist a trick that would shorten it, both visually and memory-wise. What is a way to make the following more compact and efficient?

```
       for(Particle p1 : particleList) {
            ArrayList<Particle> particleList2 = (ArrayList<Particle>) particleList.clone();
            particleList2.remove(p1);
            
            for(Particle p2 : particleList2) {
                //...treatment here involving relationships between p1 and p2...
            }   
        }
```

I suspect I could use `Iterator()` but I don't see how could that make my code more efficient or compact.

I am sorry in advance if this question is redundant, I honestly do not know how to properly formulate the question to find the answer to this question online.

Comment: In the title you talk about permutations, but the question seems about combinations. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple change that removes the cloning of the list would be to skip `p1` in the inner list instead of removing it:

```
for(Particle p1 : particleList) {
  for(Particle p2 : particleList) {
    if (p1 == p2) {
      continue;
    }
    //...treatment here involving relationships between p1 and p2...
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
particleList.forEach(a -> particleList.stream()
                                      .filter(b -> !a.equals(b))
                                      .forEach(b -> treatment(a, b))));
```